# Bad Highlight Effect

Tags: android

There is something weird in my app I just use my default Theme that use in most application but in this specific app there is a issue with highlights.
when I try to click on Menu items or tabs there is a bad black effect shows. I don't know why this happend I check all my theme and there is just nothing. I can't fine any problem with the theme.
any Idea what is happend ???
this is my Theme:

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tab_text_act</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>

</style>
```

this is my Colors:
        
    #549fe0
    #315b80
    #FFFFFF
    #FFFFFF
    #000000
    #FF80AB

```
<color name="tab_text">#8db0ad</color>
<color name="tab_text_act">#ffffff</color>

<color name="overscroll">#33b5e5</color>
<color name="light_green">#c1e25e</color>
<color name="green">#a3c639</color>
<color name="dark_green">#85a71d</color>

<color name="mrt">#fefefe</color>

<color name="style_color_primary">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="style_color_primary_dark">#303f9f</color>
<color name="style_color_accent">#448aff</color>
<color name="text_like_counter">#2b5a83</color>
```

This is my Layout :

```
<ahangme.porcen.com.ahangme.mrt.LeftDrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/id_drawerlayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">



<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>-->

        <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_icon"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ahangmesite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ahang"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/setting_icon"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/setting_icon"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- ToolBar Divider -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/white"></LinearLayout>
        <!-- ToolBar Divider END -->

        <!-- searchBar -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@drawable/search_background"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/searchbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_icon"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:hint="جستجوی موزیک"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- searchBar END -->



        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



<!--menu-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <ahangme.porcen.com.ahangme.mrt.FlowingView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_container_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

picture of problem :

[image: Highlight]

Comment: Can you add an image showing the issue?

Comment: @SujeetSinha yes added :)

Comment: @MikeM. thank you very much. resolved

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your color names don't match between theme and color files.

In MyMaterialTheme.base: `item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent`

In colors: `color name="style_color_accent">`